# Graphviz — placing nodes on a horizontal line

Tags: graphviz

I have the following graphviz file. Right now, the edge labels are placed on a horizontal line, but I want the nodes to be placed on a horizontal line instead. How can I achieve this?

```
 digraph finite_state_machine {
    node [shape = doublecircle]; q_5;
    node [shape = circle];
    q_1 -> q_2 [ label = "." ];
    q_1 -> q_2 [ label = "\epsilon" ];
    q_2 -> q_1 [ label = "\epsilon" ];
    q_2 -> q_3 [ label = "a" ];
    q_3 -> q_4 [ label = "^\wedge a" ];
    q_3 -> q_4 [ label = "\epsilon" ];
    q_4 -> q_3 [ label = "\epsilon" ];
    q_4 -> q_5 [ label = "b" ];
}
```

This is how it currently looks: [image: current output]

Comment: Please try using Rankdir="LR" for the nodes. See if it can be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`rank=same`](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#drank) to force the same rank for all nodes:

```
digraph finite_state_machine {
{
rank=same;
    node [shape = doublecircle]; q_5;
    node [shape = circle];
    q_1 -> q_2 [ label = "." ];
    q_1 -> q_2 [ label = "\epsilon" ];
    q_2 -> q_1 [ label = "\epsilon" ];
    q_2 -> q_3 [ label = "a" ];
    q_3 -> q_4 [ label = "^\wedge a" ];
    q_3 -> q_4 [ label = "\epsilon" ];
    q_4 -> q_3 [ label = "\epsilon" ];
    q_4 -> q_5 [ label = "b" ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of the frying pan and into the fire... I answered your other question.