# How to get connected neighbour nodes on the same height when drawing in GraphViz?

Tags: graph, graphviz, suffix-tree

I'm trying to draw the following (suffix-tree) using [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/):

```
digraph G {
  1[label = " "];
  2[label = " "];
  3[label = " "];
  4[label = " "];
  5[label = " "];
  6[label = " "];
  7[label = " "];
  8[label = " "];

  // edges drawn vertically, all fine.
  1 -> 2 [label="ab"];
  1 -> 3 [label=" b"];
  1 -> 4 [label=" c$"];
  2 -> 5 [label="abc$"];
  2 -> 6 [label="c$"];
  3 -> 7 [label=" abc$"];
  3 -> 8 [label="c$"];

  // node 3 should be on the right side of node 2, and
  // a cross line should be drawn horizontally

  2 -> 3 [style=dotted,label="abc$"];

}
```

The problem is, that the node reached by following edges "abc$" and "b" is not on the same height like those 2 nodes reached by following "ab" and "c$".

Has annyone encountered the same situation and could share a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah well, didnt search for the proper terms!
["placing nodes on a horizontal line"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710871/graphviz-placing-nodes-on-a-horizontal-line), offers a solution.

This code now positions the nodes 2,3,4 properly on the same "horizontal line".

```
digraph G {
  1[label = " "];
  2[label = " "];
  3[label = " "];
  4[label = " "];
  5[label = " "];
  6[label = " "];
  7[label = " "];
  8[label = " "];

  node[group=sameheight];
    { rank = same; 2; 3; 4; }

  1 -> 2 [label="ab"];
  1 -> 3 [label=" b"];
  1 -> 4 [label=" c$"];
  2 -> 3 [style=dotted];
  2 -> 5 [label="abc$"];
  2 -> 6 [label="c$"];
  3 -> 7 [label=" abc$"];
  3 -> 8 [label="c$"];
}
```

Hope it helps someone.